# Expand contents of PSObject

Tags: powershell

I have two variables as such:

```
$variables2007 = "item1;Item2;Item3;item4" -split ';'
$data2007 = "Data1;data2;data3;data4" -split ';'
```

I am trying to get these into a table so that the contents of `$variables2007` matches side by side the values of `$data2007`. I've tried a custom PSObject as such:

```
$Props2007 = [ordered]@{
  "2007Vars" = $variables2007 
  "Data2007" = $variables2007Data
}

New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Props2007
```

However, that still just writes out as tables jammed inside each other, i.e.:

```
{item1 item2 item3 item4}
```

and not a nice list of each of the contents like:

```
item1    value1
item2    value2
item3    value3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$h = [ordered]@{}
for ($i=0; $i -le $variables2007.Length; $i++) {
   $ht["$($variables2007[$i])"] = $data2007[$i]
}
[psobject]$ht

Name                           Value
----                           -----
item1                          Data1
Item2                          data2
Item3                          data3
item4                          data4
```

Answer (score 2):

just put your data into a hashtable and then enumerate the contents

```
$Props2007 = [ordered]@{

  item1 =  'Data1'
  item2 =  'Data2' 
  item3 =  'Data3' 

}

$Props2007
```

Answer (score 0):

## PSv3 and above

```
$Props2007 = @()
(0..$variables2007.Length) | %{$Props2007+=[pscustomobject]@{Variable=$variables2007[$_];Data=$data2007[$_]}}

$Props2007
```

Nice thing about this method is it's easily expandable to include more columns/members

```
(0..$variables2007.Length) | %{$Props2007+=[pscustomobject]@{Variable=$variables2007[$_];Data=$data2007[$_];SomeThirdData=$ThirdData[$_]}}
```